# How to set image in same place when screen resolution change in Unity, ios

Tags: ios, image, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have problem with ui image in canvas, basically when i put image in iphone 5 on top, in ipad that image is out of frame, I didnt write any code only use settings in inspector. how can I do that? By the way iam using Unity 5.5, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to the anchor being not properly positioned. 
Your UI item is made of 4 blue points and 4 white arrows. When you positioned the item, each blue dot gets a distance to its matching anchor (top left with top left and so on).  You can actually see that distance in the inspector.

Depending on the behaviour you want, you need to set the anchor appropriately.

For instance, if you want the item to be at the top of the canvas, you 'd set the upper anchor at the top of the canvas. The lower anchors would be positioned at the top if you want the size of the item to be constant or at the positioned of the blue dot if you want top rescale based on canvas size.

Best is that you start playing around with the anchor to understand how they work. In the inspector of the RectTransform, there are some predefined anchor and size settings, you can try.